# Facebook oauth doesn't redirect into Facebook iframe

Tags: facebook, oauth, oauth-2.0

I've encountered a strange bahaviour, when implementing a Facebook app using the iframe canvas method.

I've been following the tutorial at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/ which works very fine so far.

The page to which I send the authentification is (as the tutorial says):

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=138548612888445&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/test/facebook/return.jsf`

However, when I accept the app and allow it to access my personal data, I'm being redirected directly to the return page as topmost URL which then looks like this:

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
|  My Content                                      |
|  http://localhost:8080/test/facebook/return.jsf  |
|  ?code=...
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

However I do not wish my URL to be displayed in the topmost frame but inside the default facebook frame:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
| Facebook header                           |
+--------------------------+----------------+
| My Content               | Facebook right |
|                          | column         |
+--------------------------+----------------+
```

The strange thing is: This only happens when the user needs to authorize the app for the first time - after that, when I call `apps.facebook.com/fooapp` the content is being displayed correctly inside the iframe.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your facebook app url as the redirect uri. Alternatively, do whatever you need to do in return.jsf and then forward the user to your facebook app url.

Answer (score 1):

If you used:

```
 <script> top.location.href='$url'</script>
```

like I did, what you need to change is the `top.location.href` to `self.location.href`.